# Does Google Code provide an API?

Tags: api, github

Does google code provide an API for accessing information about a project like github does on http://developer.github.com/v3/? I haven't found any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It provides [API for its tracker](http://code.google.com/p/support/wiki/IssueTrackerAPI), but other API features present in GitHub might not yet be present.
You can use [Google API discovery](https://code.google.com/apis/explorer/#_s=discovery&_v=v1) service (based on [its lib](http://code.google.com/apis/discovery/v1/getting_started.html)) to make sure of that, though.